# Theorem for Nonlinear centers for conservative systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I am trying to find a proof for the Theorem for Nonlinear centers for conservative systems (Strogatz, Theorem 6.5.1).

“Consider the system $\dot {\vec x}= f(\vec x)$, where $\vec x = (x,y) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}$, and f is continuously differentiable. Suppose there exists a conserved quantity $E(\vec x)$ and suppose that   is an isolated fixed point $\vec x*$(i.e., there are no other fixed points in a small neighborhood surrounding $\vec x*$). If $\vec x*$ is a local minimum of *E*, then all trajectories sufficiently close to   are closed. ”

But I found only “Intuitive justifications” or plausibility arguments.

One of the key ideas of the proof is the proposition that

“Near a local maximum or minimum of a continuously differentiable real function $E(\vec x)$, where $\vec x = (x,y) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}$, the contours are closed curves”

which though it seems obvious, again I failed to find a strict justification (by myself or in the literature)

a.  Is there a rigorous proof of the theorem?

or, at least,

b.  for the proposition about the closed contours near to the extremum of a function?

Comment: Is $f$ vector-valued or scalar-valued? If the latter, then $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = f(\mathbf{x})$ is missing something.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: The $f$ in the first quotation is vector-valued, and the $f$ in the second quotation is scalar-valued! (It's not the same $f$.)

Comment: You are right,I made a misleading use of the symbolof the function. At the first proposal $f$,  denotes a vector function while at the the second a real valued function. Actually at the second proposal instead of $f$ I should have used the symbol $E$, the conserved quantity.

Comment: You can provide a rigorous proof by using a (simple) version of Morse' lemma. If I recall correctly, in V.I.Arnold's ODE you can find all the details.